# verification of the purchase via "hasReceipt"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm having some problems with IAP. I got some non consumable products in my app:

```
    builder.AddProduct("book2", ProductType.NonConsumable);
    builder.AddProduct("book3", ProductType.NonConsumable);
    builder.AddProduct("book4", ProductType.NonConsumable);
    builder.AddProduct("books234", ProductType.NonConsumable);
```

And I got an `if` statement that says :

```
    if(m_StoreController.products.WithID("books234").hasReceipt)
    {
        book2hasReceipt = true;
        book3hasReceipt = true;
        book4hasReceipt = true;
    }
```

(`book2hasReceipt`, `book3hasReceipt`, and `book4hasReceipt` are just booleanss that I'm use in my code to remove or block gameobjects in my store)

In unity things are working great, I made a build and run it on my phone, I purchased my `"books234"` item and all the books got open as I wrote in my code.

When I restarted the app, all the content was locked (as I wrote before its getting unlocked by `if(m_StoreController.products.WithID("books234").hasReceipt)")`

Why?

When I try to buy again "books234" it's says that I own the product so I must have a receipt, right?

Comment: Are you making sure that your API initializes and connects with the store before calling `m_StoreController.products.WithID("books234").hasReceipt`?

Comment: Yes. As I wrote ,  I made a purchase of the product and when I restart the app it's says that the I own the product, so I think that I have connected to the store.

Comment: *When you restart the app,* do you wait for the app to connect to the store to get receipts before asking if there is a receipt? Nothing you have said clarifies the *order of operations involved* here. Just because your game says that its purchased doesn't tell me if its doing that BEFORE or AFTER your if-statement.

Comment: I did check for a connection, I don't have any errors while opening the store on my phone. I'm receiving the price and product descriptions from it.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Just because it happens in miliseconds and you can't discern a timing difference makes no difference to your code. Which runs in order. Top to bottom. Is your if statement BEFORE or AFTER the connection to the store?

Comment: I got a "Game Manager" with the store connection in the First scene (I got "DontDestroyOnLoad", and a public "price" string that filled up), the store comes in a "popup" gameObject in the next scene. Is it safe to say that I have a store connection before the store come up? (I will add a debug massages to my code to be 1000% shure )

Comment: That does sound to be the case. I had to ask because I had a project I was working on where a coworker repeatedly tried to ask my code if a store item had been purchased *before* my code had gotten a response back from the server. I made my code throw an error. He wrapped his call in a try...catch (and assumed unpurchased). I wrote the fix for him. He removed it. As for your problem, I still am not sure why its not functioning correcly.

Comment: Thanks, for your help, I'm still trying to see how to solve the issue, I will update when I will have any progress.